# Ocaml : segfault at GC when using a custom block containing a C pointer

Tags: binding, garbage-collection, ocaml

I am trying to create a binding between a C library and an Ocaml program. I have encountered a problem when interfacing with the Gc.
I made a small program to duplicate my problem.
 The objective is to pass a custom_block allocated in the C program and containing a pointer on a C structure to the main program in Ocaml.
Then, I am trying to use it (just printing a value in the example) before cleaning (I force a call to the GC).

In the main program below in ocaml, I can either comment the line "my_print_block" or the line "Gc.compact()" and everything works fine.The address of the pointer is correct, I can print the value and the destructor is called to free the C allocated pointer.
But when the two are activated, I get a segmentation fault.

**Mail.ml**

```
type ptr

external create_block:  String.t -> ptr  = "create_block"
external print_block:  ptr -> unit       = "print_block"

let my_print_block x :unit =
  print_block x;
  ()

let main () =
        let z  = create_block "2.4" in
        let _  = my_print_block z in
        let () = Gc.compact () in
        ()

let _ = main ()
```

**Interface.c**

```
#include <caml/mlvalues.h>
#include <caml/memory.h>
#include <caml/alloc.h>
#include <caml/custom.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct foo
{
        float x;
};

void local_destroy(value v)
{
        struct foo* p = *((struct foo**)Data_custom_val(v));
        printf( "freeing p now (%p)\n with *p=%f \n", p, p->x  );
        fflush(stdout);
        free(p);
}

static struct custom_operations ops = {
        "ufpa custom_operations",
        local_destroy,
        custom_compare_default,     //default function, should not be used
        custom_hash_default,        //default function, should not be used
        custom_serialize_default,   //default function, should not be used
        custom_deserialize_default, //default function, should not be used
        custom_compare_ext_default  //default function, should not be used
};

void print_block(value type_str)
{
        CAMLparam1(type_str);
        struct foo* p =  *( (struct foo**)Data_custom_val(type_str));
        printf("value float = %f\n", p->x);
}
CAMLprim value create_block(value type_str)
{
        CAMLparam1(type_str);
        //retrieving str and creating a float value
        char* fval = String_val(type_str);
        float val  = atof(fval);

        //creating and allocating a custom_block
        CAMLlocal1(res);
        res = alloc_custom(&ops, sizeof(struct foo*), 10, 100);

        //creating and allocating a struct pointer
        struct foo* ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct foo));
        printf("allocating : %p\n", ptr);
        ptr->x = val;

        //copying the pointer itself in the custom block
        memcpy(Data_custom_val(res), &ptr, sizeof(struct foo*));
        CAMLreturn(res);
}
```

**Makefile**

```
main.native: interface.c main.ml
        rm -rf _build
        rm -f  main.native main.byte
        ocamlbuild -cflags -g interface.o
        ocamlbuild -lflag -custom -cflags -g -lflags -g main.byte -lflags interface.o
        #ocamlbuild -cflags -g -lflags -g main.native -lflags interface.o
```

With ocamldebug, the program seems to crash on my_print_block but I wasn't able to extract more sense from the trace.

With gdb, the error is located in the Gc

```
#0  0x000000000040433d in caml_oldify_one ()
#1  0x0000000000406060 in caml_oldify_local_roots ()
#2  0x000000000040470f in caml_empty_minor_heap ()
#3  0x00000000004141ca in caml_gc_compaction ()
#4  0x000000000041bfd0 in caml_interprete ()
#5  0x000000000041df48 in caml_main ()
#6  0x000000000040234c in main ()
```

I have seen several examples and I have read the documentation about C bindings at https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/intfc.html but I couldn't figure what am I doing wrong. I am using ocaml version4.04.0+flambda

Thank you for your assistance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `print_block` function uses `CAMLparam1()` so it should return with `CAMLreturn0`. I'm not sure this is your problem, it's just something I noticed. But it might be the problem.

Comment: Indeed, it was my problem. I totally overlooked that as it was a void function. Thanks a lot !